# Retrieving files from Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, data-retrieval

So I was using the free Google Compute engine trial. But I didn't realize in time that the trial is about to end, and now there are important files on the compute engine I'd really need to get.

How would I go on about retrieving files from it?
The support told me that the project is still active, just my billing is closed (since the trial ran out)

I tried to use the [*scp*](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) command in gcloud SDK shell, but couldn't really understand how to use it.

The virtual machine is running Windows Server 2016 (desktop).

Any help is highly appreciated.
I'm not very experienced here, but would really need the files nevertheless.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#end), once the free trial ends, all virtual machines still exist but are stopped (so you won't be able to access them -- and *scp* doesn't work on Windows anyway).

If you need access to the data, you'll need to upgrade the trial to a paid account, start the virtual machine, copy the data off it, and then stop it; you'll be billed for the time the virtual machine is running (so you may wish to downsize it to save money before you start it).

You only have 30 days from the end of the trial to do this; after this time, the VMs (and their disks) will be deleted (and unrecoverable by anyone).